# Is it possible for airflow task to send upstream failed error email notification?

Tags: airflow

I am using airflow to schedule some task,and I need the downstream task to send error email notification when the upstream task faile.I use the example below for testing.

```
dag_alert_task_callback = DAG(
    'dag_alert_task_callback',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None
)

t1 = PostgresOperator(task_id='create_schema',
                      sql="CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dbt_raw_data;",
                      postgres_conn_id='dbt_postgres_instance_raw_data',
                      autocommit=True,
                      database="dbtdb",
                      dag=dag_alert_task_callback)

t2 = PostgresOperator(task_id='drop_table_aisles',
                      sql="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aisles;",
                      postgres_conn_id='dbt_postgres_instance_raw_data',
                      autocommit=True,
                      database="dbtdb",
                      dag=dag_alert_task_callback)

t5 = PostgresOperator(task_id='drop_table_test',
                      sql="DROP TABLE TEST;",
                      postgres_conn_id='dbt_postgres_instance_raw_data',
                      autocommit=True,
                      database="dbtdb",
                      dag=dag_alert_task_callback)

t3 = PostgresOperator(task_id='create_aisles',
                      sql="create table if not exists dbt_raw_data.aisles (aisle_id integer, aisle varchar(100) );",
                      postgres_conn_id='dbt_postgres_instance_raw_data',
                      autocommit=True,
                      database="dbtdb",
                      dag=dag_alert_task_callback,
                      email_on_failure=True)

t4 = PostgresOperator(task_id='load_aisles',
                      sql="COPY dbt_raw_data.aisles FROM '/sample_data/aisles.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;",
                      postgres_conn_id='dbt_postgres_instance_raw_data',
                      autocommit=True,
                      database="dbtdb",
                      dag=dag_alert_task_callback)

t1 >> [t2, t5] >> t3 >> t4
```

and the dag graph view is like
[dag execute graph view]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk8wF.png
I test run the dag and delete a table named TEST in t5, but when t5 is failed,the downstream task t3 cannot to send error notification email,and it cannot fit my need.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define on_failure_callback for each task to have this code executed in case of task failure:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html?highlight=on_failure_callback

Answer (score -1):

You can write :

```
t5 = PostgresOperator(task_id='drop_table_test',
                  sql="DROP TABLE TEST;",
                  postgres_conn_id='dbt_postgres_instance_raw_data',
                  autocommit=True,
                  database="dbtdb",
                  on_failure_callback=send_email1,
                  email_on_failure=True,
                  dag=dag_alert_task_callback)
```

..then

```
def send_email1(context):
  msg = f'''
       Hi there!
       '''
  subject = f"hello world"
  send_email(to='youremail@domain.de', subject=subject, html_content=msg)
```

please keep in mind to define the on_failure_callback function to trigger an email on failure.